# Adding two references together in a query with multiple counts

Tags: mysql

I am querying a table called `Events` for players with the most bookings of both yellow and red cards (it's a soccer application). A yellow is worth 1 point and a red is worth 3.

I have this query:

```
SELECT player_id, first_name, last_name, slug, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_type.name = 'Yellow Card' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yellowAmount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_type.name = 'Red Card' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) AS redAmount
FROM   event
 INNER JOIN matches    ON event.match_id = matches.id
 INNER JOIN player     ON event.player_id = player.id
 INNER JOIN event_type ON event.event_type_id = event_type.id
WHERE  matches.league_id = 94
  AND  (event_type.name = "Yellow Card" OR event_type.name = "Red Card")
GROUP  BY player_id;
```

How do you add `yellowAmount` and `redAmount` together and use that to order the result?

I've tried this but I get an unknown column error:

```
SELECT player_id, first_name, last_name, slug,
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_type.name = 'Yellow Card' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yellowAmount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_type.name = 'Red Card' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) AS redAmount,
       SUM(yellowAmount + redAmount) AS total
FROM   event
 INNER JOIN matches    ON event.match_id = matches.id
 INNER join player     ON event.player_id = player.id
 INNER JOIN event_type ON event.event_type_id = event_type.id
WHERE  matches.league_id = 94
  AND  (event_type.name = "Yellow Card" OR event_type.name = "Red Card")
GROUP  BY player_id
ORDER  BY total DESC;
```

Comment: sum(case when event_type.name = 'Yellow Card' then 1 else 0 end) +
sum(case when event_type.name = 'Red Card' then 3 else 0 end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons this doesn't work:

1. The terms `yellowAmount` and `redAmount` do not exist in the underlying tables; you've defined them as aliases within the SELECT clause itself.  MySQL (along with most other relational databases) does not support the use of aliases from one part of the SELECT clause elsewhere in the SELECT clause.
2. Even if MySQL allowed you to refer to previously defined aliases, in this case it wouldn't make sense.  `yellowAmount` and `redAmount` are already SUMmed quantities; why/how would you SUM them again?  The SUM operation can only be applied to values that are present within the rows that you are aggregating in the GROUP BY operation.

So you must either repeat the entire CASE statement as suggested in @Strawberry's comment, or you must nest the entire query within another query that does nothing but add the two desired values:

```
select player_id, first_name, last_name, slug, yellowAmount + redAmount as total
from   (SELECT player_id, first_name, ...
        FROM   event
         INNER JOIN ...
        ...
        GROUP  BY player_id) a
order  by total desc;
```

Notice that in MySQL you *are* allowed to use the `total` alias from the SELECT clause within the ORDER BY clause (although that is not necessarily supported by all SQL implementations).